# Re arrange Java list based on a sub list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a requirement wherein I need to re-arrange numbers in a list.
Suppose I have a list of integers of size N. Then based on input grid size I partition the list and create a map of partitions. For example the following code will create a partition map.

```
public static Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> partition(List<Integer> list, int gridSize) {
        int size = list.size() - 1;
        int targetSize = size / gridSize + 1;

        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> result = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
        int number = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int end = start + targetSize - 1;

        while (start <= size) {
            Map<String, Integer> value = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            result.put("partition" + number, value);

            if (end >= size ) {
                end = size;
            }
            value.put("startIndex", ids.get(start));
            value.put("endIndex", ids.get(end));
            start += targetSize;
            end += targetSize;
            number++;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

For a list containing 100 integers from 1 to 100 and gridSize of 12 the above code will generate following partitions.

```
partition0={startIndex=1, endIndex=9}, partition1={startIndex=10, endIndex=18}, partition2={startIndex=19, endIndex=27}, partition3={startIndex=28, endIndex=36}, partition4={startIndex=37, endIndex=45}, partition5={startIndex=46, endIndex=54}, partition6={startIndex=55, endIndex=63}, partition7={startIndex=64, endIndex=72}, partition8={startIndex=73, endIndex=81}, partition9={startIndex=82, endIndex=90}, partition10={startIndex=91, endIndex=99}, partition11={startIndex=100, endIndex=100}}
{partition0={startIndex=1, endIndex=9}, partition1={startIndex=10, endIndex=18}, partition2={startIndex=19, endIndex=27}, partition3={startIndex=28, endIndex=36}, partition4={startIndex=37, endIndex=45}, partition5={startIndex=46, endIndex=54}, partition6={startIndex=55, endIndex=63}, partition7={startIndex=64, endIndex=72}, partition8={startIndex=73, endIndex=81}, partition9={startIndex=82, endIndex=90}, partition10={startIndex=91, endIndex=99}, partition11={startIndex=100, endIndex=100}
```

Now I have another list which is a sub set of the list I am partioning above.

For example, original list to be partitioned:

```
[1, 2, 3, ..... ,98, 99, 100]
```

The subset of above list:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 21, 26, 28, 33, 38, 42, 67, 74, 82, 84, 91, 92]
```

I would like to re-arrange elements in the first list based on the subset list so that the elements in the subset list are
distributed uniformly across partitions generated from the first list. The elements in the first list will remain same
but they will be re-arranged based on the subset list. Basically I would be re-arranging the list first and then creating partitions.

In the example above the subset list has 23 elements. For gridSize of 12 the 23 elements in the subset list should
be distributed across 12 partitions, so each partition should have 2 elements from subset list in this case.

This question is related to spring batch partitioning.
The integers in the list are actually the user ids to be processed by spring batch processor. Some users require more time to be processed
than others. So what can happen during partitioning is that some partitions may contain more users that take more processing time than other partiotions.
Which results in some partiotions/threads finishing before other partiotions and lying unused thereby delaying job completion.
The subset list is a list of users which take more processing time. I would like to distribute such users uniformly across partitions.

Comment: Can you also add resulting rearranged list which you would like to get out of this? I suppose you want subset list elements to be part of the starting list but uniformly distributed between partitions generated, right?

Comment: @Filip Yes, you are correct. I will try to share the resulting rearranged list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can't change your partitioning function and can only change the input list order. If that's not the case, there are far better solutions.
I'm also assuming that there are no duplicates in the lists.

This solution won't work if the subset is more than half of all values.

```java
//list_all = Arrays.asList(1, 2, ..., 100)
//list_sub = Arrays.asList(4, 6, 55)

public static List<Integer> reorder(List<Integer> all, List<Integer> sub) {
  all.removeAll(sub);
  int every = all.size() / sub.size();
  List<Integer> result = new ArrayList();
  Iterator<Integer> sub_it = sub.iterator();
  for(int i=0; i<all.size(); i++) {
     result.add(all.get(i));
     if(i%every == 0 && sub_it.hasNext())
       result.add(sub_it.next());
  }

  while(sub_it.hasNext())
    result.add(sub_it.next());
  
  return result;
}
```

Sorry for any mistakes in code, I wrote it in a hurry.

Comment: There are no duplicates in the input list as well as subset list. But the subset list may be more than half of all values. And I can change partitioning logic provided that number of partitions are always equal to the input grid size.